# How to write multiple strings to file from user input?

Tags: c

So I have this C program where I want the user to create a file with their chosen filename (works fine) and then write content to said file, which isn't working. What my current code does is write only 1 single string (first one) from user input, even though I want to save ALL text to the file. How can I do this? I've spent all afternoon trying to solve this on my own (using EOF, fprintf etc.) to no avail. Thanks in advance!

```
void createFile()
{
char userfilename[40];
char filecontent[1000];
FILE *filePointer;

printf("How do you want to name your file? ");
scanf("%s", &userfilename);
filePointer = fopen(userfilename, "w");

printf("Enter file content: ");
scanf("%s", &filecontent);
fputs(filecontent, filePointer);

fclose(filePointer);
printf("Successful.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. It's still not working tho. What do I put in a loop? I've tried !EOF and many other possibilities already... I'm getting kinda desperate lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `scanf`. `scanf` terminates after it reads the first whitespace character. Use `getline()` instead:

```
void createFile()
{
    char userfilename[40];
    char *filecontent;
    FILE *filePointer;
    size_t len = 0;     //For reading length of line
    ssize_t read;       //For number of characters read

    printf("How do you want to name your file? ");
    scanf("%s", &userfilename);
    filePointer = fopen(userfilename, "w");

    printf("Enter file content: ");
    while ((read = getline(&filecontent, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
        fprintf(filePointer, "%s", filecontent);
    }
    fclose(filePointer);
    printf("Successful.");
}
```

This should work.
Read about `getline` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html).

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work in either case though. I need a loop right? But how?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because your read a string, then write the string to the file and finally you close the file.

If you want to read from the console many lines, you must:

1) create a loop where you read from keyboard and write to the file 
2) stay in that loop until some char is read (usually EOF)

You have several ways to do what you want. Here's one solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void createFile()
{
    char userfilename[40];
    char filecontent[1000];
    FILE *filePointer;

    printf("How do you want to name your file? ");
    scanf("%s", &userfilename);
    filePointer = fopen(userfilename, "w");

    printf("Enter file content: ");

// your may read from keyboard a char at a time and write it in the file

    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        fputc(c, filePointer);

// this is your error: read one line and write that line without loop
//    scanf("%s", &filecontent);
//    fputs(filecontent, filePointer);

    fclose(filePointer);
    printf("Successful.");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    createFile(); // call your function

    return(0);
}
```

Your program terminates when you press EOF (End Of File)

In Windows EOF = CTRL + Z 
In UNIX/Linux  EOF = CTRL + D

Comment: Reading a character at a time will not look good when multi-character keys or editing keys are pressed. They will be saved in the file literally.

Comment: @alvits: the editing keys will not be saved in the file. Try yourself, and see. If editing keys are saved, reading a line at a time will do the same result. Moreover you need to terminate the saving to the file at same point, and you can do this detecting the EOF caracter.

Comment: Thanks man, I had no idea about that! Im using windows and will try it out thx!

Comment: @user7140484 - are you serious? Did you even test it yourself? This is what I get when pressing editing keys - `The quick brown fox over the lazy dog.^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[C^[[Cjumps`.

Comment: @alvits, if you get an entire line at a time you get the same result, because under the hood, read an entire line is accomplished by reading one caracter at a time.